# legacy oracle sql syntax convert python

Tags: python, sql-parser

I am converting legacy oracle sql join syntax to ANSI sql code compatible in postgres . I am using python to create utility for this purpose . So far so good from my research I have found to use `sqlparser` python library .

**Sample sql syntax :**

```
  SELECT i.product_id
,      d.language_id
,      CASE WHEN d.language_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN d.translated_name
            ELSE TRANSLATE(i.product_name USING NCHAR_CS)
       END    AS product_name
,      i.category_id
,      CASE WHEN d.language_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN d.translated_description
            ELSE TRANSLATE(i.product_description USING NCHAR_CS)
       END    AS product_description
,      i.weight_class
,      i.warranty_period
,      i.supplier_id
,      i.product_status
,      i.list_price
,      i.min_price
,      i.catalog_url
FROM   product_information  i
,      product_descriptions d
WHERE  d.product_id  (+) = i.product_id
AND    d.language_id (+) = sys_context('USERENV','LANG');
```

**expected output :**

```
  SELECT i.product_id
,      d.language_id
,      CASE WHEN d.language_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN d.translated_name
            ELSE TRANSLATE(i.product_name USING NCHAR_CS)
       END    AS product_name
,      i.category_id
,      CASE WHEN d.language_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN d.translated_description
            ELSE TRANSLATE(i.product_description USING NCHAR_CS)
       END    AS product_description
,      i.weight_class
,      i.warranty_period
,      i.supplier_id
,      i.product_status
,      i.list_price
,      i.min_price
,      i.catalog_url
FROM   product_information  i right outer join product_descriptions d

on 
d.product_id   = i.product_id 
and    d.language_id = sys_context('USERENV','LANG');
```

So far I have tried like this. I have the tokens but not sure how to interchange the position in case of legacy Oracle join syntax. If anyone can give some insights.I am very new to python .

```
import sqlparse

query= '''
    SELECT i.product_id
,      d.language_id
,      CASE WHEN d.language_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN d.translated_name
            ELSE TRANSLATE(i.product_name USING NCHAR_CS)
       END    AS product_name
,      i.category_id
,      CASE WHEN d.language_id IS NOT NULL
            THEN d.translated_description
            ELSE TRANSLATE(i.product_description USING NCHAR_CS)
       END    AS product_description
,      i.weight_class
,      i.warranty_period
,      i.supplier_id
,      i.product_status
,      i.list_price
,      i.min_price
,      i.catalog_url
FROM   product_information  i
,      product_descriptions d
WHERE  d.product_id  (+) = i.product_id
AND    d.language_id (+) = sys_context('USERENV','LANG')'''


res=sqlparse.parse(query)
stmt = res[0]
print (stmt.tokens[-1])
```

Output I am getting 
the where clause joins

```
WHERE  d.product_id  (+) = i.product_id
AND    d.language_id (+) = sys_context('USERENV','LANG');
```

I am stuck here , how to rewrite it as

```
FROM   product_information  i right outer join product_descriptions d    
on  d.product_id   = i.product_id 
and    d.language_id = sys_context('USERENV','LANG');
```

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: @TrippKinetics I can access the where clause using token[-1]. Updated my question to add output I am getting . but how to rewrite it as right outer join .

Comment: It looks like the parser doesn't do any conversion. I suspect it will be necessary to use something else.